# How to call variables and function from outside of a module in NestJS?

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I have some helper functions inside the `/src/common/helper/cash.helper.ts`. When I call this function from a module, I get the following error.

`Error: Cannot find module './../../../src/common/helper/cast.helper' Require stack:`

However, the e2e tests are working without any problem. Here, you can see the folder structure.

When I change the import to absolute path `import { toNumber } from 'src/common/helper/cast.helper'`; It's working, but the e2e tests are not working.

[image]

What's wrong here? How can I use common functions and constants across all the modules in NestJS?

Comment: don't use absolute paths. Otherwise you'll need to set up the `moduleNameMapper` on jest config file.

Comment: you should be able to do src/common/helper/cast.helper no ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the following to fix the issue.

1. I changed the import to absolute path import `{ toNumber } from 'src/common/helper/cast.helper'`;
2. To fix the e2e test, I have added `"moduleDirectories": ["<rootDir>/../", "node_modules"]` to the jest-e2e.json.

Answer (score 0):

Well I had the same problem and I solved kind of a bit different.

I created a [library](https://docs.nestjs.com/cli/libraries) `shared`:
`nest g library shared`
Created inside of the library a new typescript file like:

```
//file: /libs/shared/src/general.helper.ts

export function helloworld() {}
```

And imported it into the controller:

```
import { helloworld } from '@app/shared';
```